# Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0

Tags: react-native

I want to use this library:

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

but I got this error message:

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

connected my device galaxy S4 to my mac os and I followed this methods:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app my-app
$ cd my-app/
$ npm start
```

on my screen device I got this error:

```
something went wrong 

could not load exp://172.20.10.4:19000 network not response timed out
```

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing the package `create-react-native-app` again if that helps.

Comment: This is a stupid bug that has been open in that tutorial's repo for over 8 months without a single comment from any of the developers: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/539

Comment: Did you already connected your device and your computer in the same wifi network ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug for the current package of either `create-react-native-app` or one of the modules it consumes. We can fix this by addressing the error directly as-stated by providing an SDK version that's actually supported. Right now, v `25.0.0` is the latest.

Open the `app.json` and change this line (it might be higher than v 27 by the time you read this):
`"sdkVersion": "27.0.0"`

to this line:
`"sdkVersion": "25.0.0"`

Then from that directory, run `npm install` to re-install the correct SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I was having code written by one of my colleagues but I faced the same problem while running it and none of the above-mentioned methods could solve it for me. Here is how I made it up and running:

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save
npm install -g expo-cli --save
expo r -c //(r is short for start, and -c is short for --clear)
```

**NOTE:**
Before the above-mentioned commands I also tried doing :

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-native-app
npm i -g create-react-native-app
```

So maybe a combination of both the approaches solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using creating App using following commands

```
npm install exp --global
exp init my-new-project
cd my-new-project
exp start
```

You should prefer use expo commands to create app. I try to change sdkVersion of last to expo app not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is Published in 2020,
Fix this Error in 3 steps:

First step: I changed the value of `expo` in `package.json` file to the latest supported version, according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

Second step: I changed the value of `sdkVersion` in `app.json` file to the same value of `expo` in `package.json`.( equal number to last step).

Third step : I changed the value of `react-native` in `package.json` file to the same value of `React Native Version` , according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

now your ready to go.

use `npm install` to install specified version of dependencies and then `npm start` to run the project

Answer (score -1):

About solutions are not working for me.

In my case, I solved this problem by connecting the same wifi network on both mobile and my system